# Setting the Slider.Value with same value is not firing ValueChanged event in C#?

Tags: c#, slider

I have a slider control. When I change the thumb it is raising the ValueChanged event as expected.

The problem is when the Slider.Value is having some value and assigning with the same value is not firing the ValueChanged event.

What is the best to way to raise the event?

Comment: Why would you want to raise the changed event when the value DOES NOT change?

Comment: Why do you need to raise the event if the value's not changed?

Comment: Actually I am using the same slider control for two views(usercontrol), when changing the view, it should retain the old value. Setting the value in different view should trigger the ValueChanged event, so that I can do other logic.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your comments I would suggest to use a DataBinding. Bind the property "Value" to some variable and only change the value of that variable.

It might be very interesting for you to look at the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. Here is an interesting tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I am not using the DataBinding.